# Стандартная сборка vue cli. Отсутствует папка build и webpack.base.conf.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Собственно сабж. Создал стандартный проект vue.cli для обучения. В туториалах ясно было видно наличие папки build или хотя бы файла webpack.conf.js . Но данный фалй как и папка отсутствуют. Как найти этот файл если он скрыт? На картинке ниже наличие тех фалов проекта которые присутствуют в стандартной сборке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какую команду вы вводили для создания проекта?

Comment: Использовал стандартное создание проекта через web.storm

Comment: Это была установка с помощью `vue-cli`  v 3.0. https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/  Туториалы же, скорее всего, написаны по `vue-cli`  v 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь, начиная с `vue-cli 3`, конфигурации `webpack` надо править в файле `vue.config.js`, которого тоже, собственно, нет. Его надо создать в корне проекта, там же, где и `package.json`. [Документация](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/webpack.html) подробнее расскажет. Тем более по-русски всё.